# Varargs polluting the heap

Tags: java, generics, variadic-functions

Java doesn't have a literal map syntax so I was playing with ways to initialise maps literal-ish-ly. The compiler warned `Possible heap pollution from parameterized vararg type` which was new to me so I read about that. I think I'm safe to suppress these warnings with the relevant annotations. But I have two related questions.

1. Am I right that it's ok to suppress the warnings in this case? (for the code below)
2. Why do I need two annotations for the `keys` method? Omitting either of them gets me a variation on the "heap pollution" warning, but both sound the same to me.

You don't have to critique the code. I was just playing.

Here's the code.

```
import java.util.*;

public class MapMaker<K, V>{
    private K [] m_keys;

    @SafeVarargs
    @SuppressWarnings("varargs")
    public final MapMaker<K, V> keys( final K... keys ){
        m_keys = keys;
        return this;
    }

    @SafeVarargs
    public final Map<K, V> values( final V... values ){
        if ( values.length != m_keys.length )
            throw new IllegalArgumentException( "Mismatch - keys: " + m_keys.length + ", values " + values.length );

        final Map<K, V> result = new HashMap<>();

        for ( int i = 0; i < m_keys.length; i++ )
            result.put( m_keys[ i ], values[ i ] );

        return result;
    }

    public static void main( String [] args ){
        final Map<Integer, String> mapIntStr = new MapMaker<Integer, String>()
                .keys  ( 1,     2,     3       )
                .values( "One", "Two", "Three" );

        System.out.println( mapIntStr );

        final Map<String, String> mapStrStr = new MapMaker<String, String>()
                .keys  ( "1" )
                .values( "One", "Two" );
    }
}
```

The output is

```
{1=One, 2=Two, 3=Three}
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Mismatch - keys: 1, values 2
    at MapMaker.values(MapMaker.java:16)
    at MapMaker.main(MapMaker.java:35)
```

Comment: When I paste your code into IntelliJ, it complains if I remove `@SafeVarargs`, but I get no warnings from the IDE nor compiler if I remove `@SuppressWarnings("varargs")`.

Comment: @MikeStrobel : I get the following. I'm using javac 1.8.0_152
`MapMaker.java:9: warning: [varargs] Varargs method could cause heap pollution from non-reifiable varargs parameter keys`

Comment: Do you know that in Java 9 there is a static factory method `Map.of(key, value, key, value, ...)`?

Comment: @DodgyCodeException yes, but I can't use Java 9 at work because we've only recently moved to Java 8. Since the first Java code I wrote in 1999 and I've never been on the latest version.

Comment: We're even worse: stuck on Java 7. I only do Java 9 at home just to be employable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Am I right that it's ok to suppress the warnings in this case?

Here the `Varargs` are safely used as  :

- `K` and `V` argument types are bounded at compile time on the generics specified as you instantiate `MapMaker` :

  `final Map<Integer, String> mapIntStr = new MapMaker<Integer, String>()`
- You don't perform unsafe casts with the vargs variables and you don't assign them to a declared `Object[]` array to value it with incompatible objects that could cause `java.lang.ArrayStoreException` (that is not a Heap pollution but that is also problematic).
- You use an array of generic and not an array of a generic collection. Heap pollution is less common in this configuration as you don't have a collection that may contain incompatible elements that could trigger a `ClassCastException`.

So yes `@SafeVarargs` makes sense.

---

> Why do I need two annotations for the keys method?

Annotating the `keys()` method with these two methods :

```
@SafeVarargs
@SuppressWarnings("varargs")
```

should not be required.

`@SafeVarargs` is indeed enough as `java.lang.SafeVarargs` javadoc states :

> Applying this annotation to a method or constructor **suppresses
>   unchecked warnings** about a non-reifiable variable arity (vararg) type
>   and suppresses unchecked warnings about parameterized array creation
>   at call sites.

You should probably check your IDE configuration about it.
I tested with `javac` and no warning is emitted by using only the `@SafeVarargs` annotation.

Comment: I assume these annotations are somehow related to the problem of generic array creation in Java, like e.g: `T[] a = (T[]) new Object[2];` - where T is a generic type.

Comment: @davidxxx - if I remove `@SuppressWarnings("varargs")` I get `MapMaker.java:9: warning: [varargs] Varargs method could cause heap pollution from non-reifiable varargs parameter keys` despite still having `@SafeVarargs`. I'm using javac 1.8.0_152 so maybe that's fixed in 1.9?

Comment: @gil.fernandes It may indeed cause issue as you perform unsafe casts and or assigns a typed thing to a very broad type as Object that can accepts everything. Excellent resource : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/nonReifiableVarargsType.html

Comment: @Jonathan I am using javac 1.8.0_121 (older than you) and it is ok for me. Which OS are you using ? Me, Windows.

Comment: @davidxxx - Windows 7, Oracle JDK. I'm happy with your answer because it amounts to me not misunderstanding something, and there just being a compiler quirk. :-)